# Powershell file download and Task Scheduler

Tags: xml, powershell, download, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I am a beginner. I tried to schedule a download with local Windows 10's powershell.
Tested in powershell, the script work and successful download the files.

```
$client = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://example.com&format=xml&limit=50","C:\folder\1-50.xml")
```

However, when I tried to schedule in Windows Task Scheduler(Since there are 24 xml indeed) 
[Scheduler Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NPa3.png)

It always runs into errors.
e.g.
missing ')' in method call...
unexpected token...
the ampersand (&) character is not allowed...

Think it should be some syntax error on the Task Scheduler side, but I am not sure what to update as I learnt the powershell script from Googleing only

What should I update on the command?
Or should I use other script to achieve that instead?

Answer (score 0):

In powershell there is a simpler way to download files, using Invoke-WebRequest:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $URL -OutFile $Path
```